# Suitable paint for vent guard?

Tags: painting, paint, vinyl

I have several external vent guards that I bought from the local hardware store.  From the look and feel of it, I believe that the material is some sort of vinyl.

For what it's worth it's a Lambro L1491W 4" plastic pest guard.  All I can find online is that it is "plastic".

And FWIW again, I located the company's website and sent them a message. Of course their office closed about 15 minutes ago.

[image]

But given that my house isn't bright white, I want to color match it so the guard doesn't stick out like a sore thumb.

I've tried using various spray paints to paint it, including some that claim the paint will adhere to anything, but none of the paint I've tried is adhering.

What would be a suitable type of paint and/or surface treatment in order to achieve my color goals?

Comment: I suspect that's polyethylene. If you find a recycling code on it (triangle arrow symbol) you'll know. You'll have to find a paint or primer that claims to bond to plastic. That's a notoriously difficult material to paint with any durability.

Comment: @isherwood I've tried paints that claim they bond to plastic, but nothing suitable yet (which is why I am here).   And I just went to the retailers site and looked at the product details, and all it says about the material is that it is "plastic".  D'uh!! /s

Comment: @isherwood Also, no recycling mark on it, and it claims to be made in the USA as well.

Comment: And I need a lot of shrubbery to hide a vent guard 12 feet up in the air, that also faces the street, on a house that is a sand brown!

Comment: I that case I suggest a different solution. For one thing, it takes a ton of spray paint to get all those openings and faces adequately colored. You might be shocked.

Comment: @isherwood  Trust me, I already know!